# gcc compile errors

Tags: linux

I am  getting these errors when I compile sim_routing.cc program by this command

```
../../bin/cxx sim_routing.cc
g++ -Wall -o sim_routing sim_routing.cxx
```

following errors are produced:

```
../../common/priority_q.h : In member function 'bool guardedQueue<ITEM>::Validate(Const char*);
error : there are no argument to 'strcat' that depend on template parameter so a declaration of 'strcat' must be avaible.
error : <if you use -fpermissive  g++ will accept your code but allowing use of undeclared name is deprecated>
```

When I tried to change commom/priority_q.h, it shows it is read only; file changes cannot be accepted.

How these errors can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

`#include <cstring>` *before* the header triggering your error.